# Is it possible to wrap a div using JQuery and dynamically create a copy of the div with the contained elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Div containing multiple textfields. My code to wrap the div is simple and works fine. However I am wondering is it possible to wrap the div, create a new div with the contents, generate a new html input and then unwrap the first div using .unwrap() and repeat the process? The result displays in a modal window so only one div can be created at a time.

```
function adminCredential(){
    $('#newAdminCredential').on('click',function() {
        var tempAdminCredential = $("#newCredential").wrapInner("<div id='adminCredential'></div>");
        var adminCredential = tempAdminCredential.clone();
        $("#newCredential").unwrap("<div id ='adminCredential'></div>");

    });
}

<div id="newCredential" class="credentialWindow"> 
<div class="sectionHeader">Credential</div>
<div class="sectionContent">
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="customer_id[]" value="42">
        <table class="small one-column">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Type
</td>
            <td class="data">
                <select id="type" name="type[]">
                    <option>--None--</option>
                    </select> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Context Type
</td>
            <td class="data">
                <select id="contextType" name="contextType[]">
                <option value=""></option>
                </select> 
            </td>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Above is just a taste of what my div looks like(I only included the first half of the div so I am well aware some tags don't have an close tag)

Thank you in advance I hope I explained what I'm try to achieve clearly.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Show us what you have tried, please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve but to `copy` a div's html you can use `var theHTML = $("#yourDivID").html()` to fill another div with that html you can `$("#yourOtherDiv").html(theHTML)`

Comment: $('div').clone()   https://api.jquery.com/clone/   Is that what you mean?

Comment: So why I want to do it is because I need to create multiple objects from the same class.

Comment: Yes thats what I'm trying. Sorry I had to remove my code snippet as it wasn't legible, I'll edit my first post.